# Combining multiple files and columns in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

So i have 2 files, a list of people, and a list of people and a bit of a description.
im trying to combine these 2 files with AWK, but i have never used AWK on more than one file at a time and i just cant figure it out.

Maybe AWK isnt the easiest way to do it, but i just assumed it is.

file 1

```
5 7/5/93 Steve
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale
```

file 2

```
dale - is a cool guy
Steve - works at cosco
dale - is a cool guy
Steve - works at cosco
Steve - works at cosco
```

OUTPUT

```
5 7/5/93 Steve - works at cosco
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
```

Comment: I don't think there is a POSIX one liner: just write a Python script that parses the files into dicts, then outputs what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk -F" - " 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {split($0,b," ");print $0 (a[b[3]]?FS a[b[3]]:"")}' file2 file1
5 7/5/93 Steve - works at home
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
```

`awk` is very good to join files based on different criteria.

In your `file 2` you do repeat data for same person. That works fine.  If there are different data for one and same person, `awk` will use the last it find and ignore all other.

---

Another variation:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {sub(/ /,"| ");split($0,f,"|");a[f[1]]=f[2];next} {print $0 a[$3]}' file2 file1
5 7/5/93 Steve - works at home
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
21 21/1/90 Bob
52 1/1/89 dale - is a cool guy
```

Here is how it works:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {               # Run this section for the first file in the list (file2)
    sub(/ /,"| ")       # Change first space to "| " so we can split username from data
    split($0,f,"|")     # Split the sting in to "f" array devided by "|"
    a[f[1]]=f[2]        # Store data into array "a" using username as index
    next}               # Skip the next record.
    {                   # Run this section for file1
    print $0 a[$3]}     # Print all data from file1 and the data from array "a" (the user information)
    ' file2 file1       # Read the two files.
```

Comment: Good but it misses `-`.

Comment: Now, i'm going to take a notes of your code for studying it later. And +1 from me for the correction.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I made it some more understandable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bash:

```
while read line; do
    while read name trait; do
        if [[ $line == *"$name" ]]; then
            line="$line $trait"
            break
        fi
    done < file2
    echo $line
done < file1
```